# Using one similar route url for two different parameter types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I have following routes in place in my project, what I want to do here use one similar looking route url but direct it to two different actions based over the parameter provided, if the given parameter is a *string* it should pick the `Search` route and if the parameter is a *digit/integer* than it should pick the `GetCategory` route and to achieve this I have written the following code after seeking some existing online help here over SO, but this doesn’t seems to be working as expected.

No matter what the parameter value is it always picks whichever route appears first in the list.

```
//routes.MapRoute("GetCategory", "{pId}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Post", pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
routes.MapRoute("Search", "{category}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Search", category = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("GetCategory", "{pId}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Post", pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```

Can anybody help me out with what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this approach

```
routes.MapRoute("GetCategory", "{pId}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Post" },new {pId = @"\d"});
routes.MapRoute("Search", "{category}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Search", category = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You should apply restrictions on your params within constraints argument, not in defaults section.

Comment: yea, figured it out the issue was not having a separate `new` for specifying parameter, works well now. thankyou also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the GetCategory route up above the other one. The problem with the Search route is you don't have a constraint on it so it would match anything. If you moved the GetCategory route to the top and provided a string, it wouldn't match since it is not a digit and would move to the next one.

Comment: tried still not working.. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the `constraint` ive provided `pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" })` can you verify is this correct?